# page by page Vs. page after page

Tags: word-choice, collocations

I am wondering which option I should chose to convey that I turn the pages of my book while reading one by one.

I read my book ...

page by page

or

page after page?

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Page by page* implies 'one page after another without missing any' (which surely is the normal way to read a book, unless it's a reference book?).

*[Noun] after [noun]* would emphasise that there were many of them.

> It happened time after time.
>
> I lay awake night after night.